# Postfix: Allow only one specific sender to send email

Tags: server, email, postfix

I want to allow only one sender with a specific address to send email on the localhost

main.cf

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
      check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/senders,
      reject
```

senders

```
sender@somewhere.net   OK
```

Tried several combinations, REGEXP, etc, doesn't work

Am I missing other options?

**UPDATE:**

Scenario:

I want to restrict which local accounts can use the local Postfix SMTP service. For example, I only want to allow 'root' account to use the service, or some other who has a specific sender address. Tried numerous configs, but none of them worked.

I'm using a Smarthost to relay the emails

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "send email on the localhost"...

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! _What_ is that doesn't work? It allows **other** addresses to send? Or it **does not** allow `sender@somewhere.net` ?

Comment: It does not block any of the emails, all of them pass. I want a scenario that blocks all, except one. Thanks for the reply

Comment: did you postmap /etc/postfix/senders ?

Comment: when you settedup mail. only root can send mail.